# I published one package on npm, but it's not showing in the search list when i am going to search

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-publish

I published one package as a public & i am trying to search it on npm
(https://www.npmjs.com/), but there is no package available with that name on npm.

Tried with:

npm install package-name  -> working fine

Here is the package link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/and-or-search

Is there any thing i am missing?

Comment: Try the command: `npm show <package-name>`

Comment: It's working fine through command line. I am asking about..when i am going to search through npm search tab in the browser. It's not showing in the search list.

Comment: It's going to take sometime to reflect in the actual site. But it will eventually. In a couple of hours generally.

Comment: You can see now that the last publish is `2 hours ago` now in the website.

Comment: Thanks @Faizuddin Mohammed. It's reflected. Yes, It take a some time to reflect.

Answer (score 15):

The npm website takes time to show the latest packages or package versions because of the delays in CDN, website cache etc.

But it will show up eventually. Meanwhile, you can check for the package with:

```
npm show <package-name>
```

This will output all the versions of the package as well so you can be confident that the package exists or the latest version is published.

Your package now shows up correctly in npm website at https://www.npmjs.com/package/and-or-search

Answer (score 5):

It takes some time for website to show the latest version, but it also takes some time for `npm show <package-name>` From my experience I haven't noticed difference between the command and between the website. You should also receive email.

**I recommend waiting a few minutes.**

Comment: Well, I get npm show output from a package while the website has no trace in search results (the package is public since more than a day and the latest version pusshed 11 hours from that query timestamp)